# How should I (or should I at all) disambiguate organizations with very similar names?

Tags: professionalism, communication

I used to work for a mid-sized tech R&D company in Japan. I wont reveal their name, but let's pretend they are called Apple株式会社. This would translate to Apple Inc. or Apple Co. in English. Importantly, this is *not* the world-famous Apple Inc with a market cap of almost $3 trillion.

Everyone in Japan knows that Apple株式会社 isn't Apple Inc, because Apple isn't a Japanese company, and it's fairly common for a local company to share a name with a foreign company (especially if they've been around longer than the now larger foreign company). There's even a company even larger than Apple株式会社 called 株式会社Apple, which I have disambiguate between (but the Japanese are used to this).

I'm struggling with how to make this obvious to people outside of Japan, though.

If I put "Apple株式会社", on a CV, pitch deck, etc. a lot of people think I worked for the Japanese division of Apple. If I put "Apple Inc" or "Apple Co", that's obviously misleading. "Apple株式会社 (Japan)" doesn't do much, and "Apple株式会社 (not the Apple you know, a different one from Japan)" doesn't really appeal to me.

Is there a smart way to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you use the Latin script spelling of the Japanese name, instead?

Comment: So instead of "Apple Co" it would be "Apple Kabushiki Gaisha" (which translates to "Apple Co")?

Comment: "Apple Kabushiki Gaisha" looks distinctive, even though someone who knows Japanese might understand the translation, especially because this is for "people outside of Japan".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the disambiguation is required only for a few well known household names.

One way to handle this is to add a few descriptive words to each company and explicitly disambiguate where you feel its necessary. For example

```
2000-2001 Chinook Communication, Lexington MA, USA (Communication Startup, now defunct)
2010-2015 Apple Inc., Sendai, Japan (mid sized IT company, not Apple Inc, USA)
```

Answer (score -5):

On your resume, people don't really care about the names of the employers you list, if they aren't household names. Someone applied to me once listing a company name like "R M Smith Holdings" and during the interview it turned out that this was the local McDonalds franchisee and he felt funny about putting McDonalds on his resume.

You could, for example, list the company as "Ringo" - a transliteration of the Japanese word for apple. This wouldn't be deceptive but would also not lead people to believe you're claiming to have worked for the bigger Apple. While it wouldn't enable people to investigate or evaluate your former employer, that isn't going to be possible anyway, since all their searches will lead to the bigger compnay. Or you could just not worry about it, and clear things up in the interview. You will have to use the real name when you provide your references, but those are always "on request" so you'll be able to give the "not that Apple" clarification then.

Comment: >"On your resume, people don't really care about the names of the employers you list, if they aren't household names?"
Really? This is news to me. When I interview people, I always look up the companies listed on their resume to get a feel for what sort of environments they've worked in.

Comment: You must get far less resumes than I do. But anyway a well written resume tells me what sort of environments they've worked in, possibly even the size of the company. If I have more questions I can ask them at the interview.

Comment: Past companies is one of the first things I look at. I know most companies in my field quite well and there are some that are A LOT better than others.